# How to log http response from iframe loaded in Apache Cordova Application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, iframe

I have an Apache Cordova Application that uses the AngularJS framework.  A service is pulling in a list of JSON objects that contain 1 url each to populate a menu.  Once the user selects one of the menu items the application grabs the url from the object and binds it into an iframe.  I have all of this working however, with one of my urls the page is not displaying.  Is there a way I can log the response of the iframe after it is loaded?

Here is a snippet from the partial.

```
 <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left pharma_setting_icon1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left text-center store_name_main_div"><strong>{{ label }}</strong></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 pull-right nav-icon-header">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-wrapper iframe-holder">
        <iframe data-ng-src="{{ currentUrl }}"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Is there an easy way to use javascript to log the response of this iframe if I assign it an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some changes in answer on this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7647123/4010758)

You should declare a global variable in parent like :

```
<script> var myglobal; </script>
```

Then in your iframe html codes you can change that global variable by calling parent keyword , like :

```
<script>  parent.myglobal='something'; </script>
```

Comment: I haven't actually verified it works yet since we did a work around, but since you are the only one who responded I gave it to you.  Thanks for the info.