# On click function is not defined and i dont know why

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have to validate an email and a phone. It is not necessary that both are mandatory, just one is enough.
When i click my button, the code error is that handleValidation is not defined, but i do not why. Even the console don't print the console.log.

Here the HTML:

```
        <form class="form-group p-4">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex flex-column">
                <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0 p-3 m-1" id="name" required
                    placeholder="NOMBRE Y APELLIDO">
                <input type="email" class="form-control rounded-0 p-3 m-1" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control rounded-0 p-3 m-1" id="phone" placeholder="TELÉFONO">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-flex flex-column">
                <textarea id="message" class="form-control rounded-0 h-100 p-3 m-1" required
                    placeholder="DEJANOS TU MENSAJE"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-3 d-flex flex-column float-right align-items-end">
                <button onclick="handleValidation()" id="send-btn"
                    class="main-btn btn btn-primary col-12 rounded-0 p-2 mt-3">ENVIAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here the JS:

```
let email = document.querySelector("#email");
let tel = document.querySelector("#phone");


const emailVal = () => {
  if (!(/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)/.test(email))) {
    console.log("bad")
    return false;
  }
  console.log("good")
  return true;
}


const telVal = () => {
  if (!(/^\d{9}$/.test(tel))) {
    console.log("bad")
    return false;
  }
  console.log("good");
  return true;
}


const handleValidation = () => {
  if (emailVal() === true || telVal() === true) {
    alert("tu consulta fue enviada satisfactoriamente");
  } else {
    alert("el email y/o el teléfono son necesarios para contactarte");
  }
}
```

Comment: if you use `function handleValidation () {` - does it work? `const` and `let` do not work the same in the global scope as `function` and `var` - in other words, using `onclick=foo` would need a `foo` function in global scope i.e. `window.foo`,  to work - `const`, `let` and `class` for that matter don't add to the global (window) object - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452697/what-is-the-proper-to-write-a-global-const-in-javascript-es6/51923076

Answer (score 1):

- Set an event listener in the script instead of onclick attribute
- You do not get the values of the inputs but the inputs
- Input values should be grabbed into the validations functions, not outside
- Your email regex doesn't seems to work (I didn't check the phone number one)

If you correct all this problems, your script should look like that :

```js
const emailVal = () => {
  let email = document.querySelector("#email").value;  
  if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(email))) {
    console.log("bad email")
    return false;
  }
  console.log("good")
  return true;
}

const telVal = () => {
  let tel = document.querySelector("#phone").value;
  if (!(/^\d{9}$/.test(tel))) {
    console.log("bad tel")
    return false;
  }
  console.log("good");
  return true;
}

const handleValidation = () => {
  if (emailVal() || telVal()) {
    alert("tu consulta fue enviada satisfactoriamente");
  } else {
    alert("el email y/o el teléfono son necesarios para contactarte");
  }
}

document.getElementById('send-btn').addEventListener('click', handleValidation);
```

You will also have to remove your button onclick attribute of course.
Source for email validation regex : https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code in jsfiddle. I receive very time "el email y/o el teléfono son necesarios para contactarte". So code is correct to some extends. I suggest add the JSSript after the html and vice versa. I'm mixing this all time up.