# Can an iframe access main window objects [like login token]?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have a Main Window [parent window] and an Iframe from third party in it.
I have defined some global constant in my main window, which holds confidential information like login token. I also have a two way message communication between my main window and iframe.

Can the iframe window access my other global constants from main window ?
How to safe guard them, if such an access is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the main window is the parent window that contains the iframe. If you're attaching your confidential information to the `window` object then that's probably not safe.

The child iframe can access the parent window via `window.top`.

```
// in parent window
window.confidentialInfo = "foo";

// in iframe
console.log(window.top.confidentialInfo);
// prints "foo"
```

Otherwise, hard to say without more information.

Comment: yes main window is parent window, which contains iframe. No I am not attaching token to window object instead saving it as separate global constant.

Comment: Then as long as you don't expose them somewhere in the two-way message channel, I'd think it would be fine.

Comment: Well I guess as long as the iframe is served from a different domain. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647042/sharing-global-javascript-variable-of-a-page-with-an-iframe-within-that-page